# Is there a possibility to make my query in SQL run faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run a query that would produce only 2 million lines and 12 columns. However my query has been running for 6 hours... I would like to ask if there is anything I can do to speed it up and if there are general tips.

I am still a beginner in SQL and your help is highly appreciated

```
INSERT INTO @ORSOID values (321) --UK
INSERT INTO @ORSOID values (368) --DE 
SET @startorderdate = '4/1/2019' --'1/1/2017' --EDIT THESE
SET @endorderdate = '6/30/2019'  --EDIT THESE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---step 1 for the list of opids and check the table to see if more columns that are needed are present to include them 
--Create a list of relevant OpIDs for the selected time period
select
op1.oporid,
op1.opcurrentponum, 
o.orcompletedate, 
o.orsoid, 
op1.opid, 
op1.opreplacesopid, 
op1.opreplacedbyopid, 
op1.OpSplitFromOpID, 
op1.opsuid, 
op1.opprsku, 
--op1.orosid,
op1.opdatenew,
OPCOMPONENTMANUFACTURERPARTID

into csn_junk.dbo.SCOpid
from csn_order..vworder o with (nolock) 
inner join csn_order..vworderproduct op1 with (nolock) on oporid = orid
LEFT JOIN  CSN_ORDER..TBLORDERPRODUCT v WITH (NOLOCK) on op1.opid = v.OpID
where op1.OpPrGiftCertificate = 0 
and orcompletedate between @startorderdate and  @endorderdate 
and orsoid in (select soid from @orsoid) 

Select * From csn_junk.dbo.SCOpid
```

Comment: Have you made sure all appropriate indices exist?

Comment: You want to read about "indexes". Basically, you should have indexes, in that case, on your IDs and consider having them also on your dates in your `where`. I don't have enough context to be sure but that will have an impact.

Comment: @JuliaLeder yes the code works fine on a small subset but on the whole tables (which should result in 2 million data points) it takes i guess more than expected

Comment: Speed will depend on presence of indices, but also on availability of sufficient memory, vacuum status, how busy the system is, etc.  There isn't usually a simple answer to this (besides adding a missing index) and the solution may be database specific.  I suggest you add a database-specific tag to your question.

Comment: Tip: read this article about NOLOCK.  https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no way to know why a query is running on for many hours on a server we don't have access to or without any metrics (i.e an. execution plan or CPU/Memory/IO metrics.) Also, without any `DDL` there it's impossible to  understand what's going on with your query.

**General Guidelines for troubleshooting slow data modification:**

---

**Getting the right metrics**

The first thing I'd do is run task manager on that server and see if you have a server issue or a query issue. Is the CPU pegged to 100%? If so, is sqlservr.exe the cause? How often do you run this query? How fast is it normally?

There are a number of native and 3rd party tools for collecting good metrics. Execution plans, DMFs and DMVs, Extended Events, SQL Traces, Query Store. You also have great third party tools like Brent Ozar's suite of tools, Adam Machanic's sp_whoisactive.

There's a saying in the BI World: **If you can't *measure* it, you can't *manage* it.** If you can't measure what's causing your queries to be slow, you won't know where to start.

Big updates like this can cause locking, blocking, lock-escalation and even deadlocks.

**Understand execution plans, specifically actual execution plans.**

I write my code in SSMS with "Show execution plan" turned on. I always want to know what my query is doing. You can also view the execution plans after the fact by capturing them using SQL Traces (via the SQL Profiler) or Extended Events.

This is a huge topic so I'll just mention some things off the top of my head that I look for in my plans when troubleshooting slow queries: Sorts, Key Lookups, RID lookups, Scans against large tables (e.g. you scan an entire 10,000,000 row table to retrieve 12,000 rows - for this you want a seek.) Sometimes there will be warnings in the execution plan such as a "tempdb spill" - these are bad. Sometimes the plan will call out "missing indexes" - a topic unto itself. Which brings me to...

**INDEXES**

This is where execution plans, DMV and other SQL monitoring tools really come in handy. The rule of thumb is, when you are doing SELECT queries it's nice to have plenty of good indexes available for the optimizer to chose; in a normalized data mart for example, more are better. For INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations you want as few indexes possible because each one associated with the query/data in the query is modified. For a big insert like the one you are doing, fewer indexes would be better on `csn_junk.dbo.SCOpid` and, as mentioned in the comments below your post, you want the correct indexes to support the tables used for the update.

**CONSTRAINTS**

Constraints slow data modification. The present referential integrity constraints (Primary/Foreign keys) and UNIQUE constraints will impact performance. CHECK constraints can as well; *CHECK constraints that use a T-SQL scalar function will absolutely destroy data modification performance more than almost anything else I can think of* except for scalar UDFs as CHECK constraints that also access other tables this can slow an insert that should a minute to several hours.

**MDF & LDF file growth**

A 2,000,000 row+/12 column insert is going to cause the associated MDF and LDF files to grow substantially. If your data files (.MDF or .NDF) or Log File (.LDF) fill up they will auto-grow to create space. This slows queries that run in seconds to minutes, especially when your auto-growth settings are bad. See: [SQL Server Database Growth and Autogrowth Settings](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/sql-server-database-growth-and-autogrowth-settings/)

Whenever I have a query that always runs for 10 seconds and now, out of nowhere, it's running for minutes. Assuming it's not a deadlock or server issue I will check for MDF or LDF autogrowth as this is often the culprit. Often you have a log file that needs to be shrunk (via log backup or manually depending on the recovery model.) This brings me to batching:

**Batching**

Huge inserts chew up log space and take forever to roll back if the query fails. Making things worse - cancelling a huge insert (or trying to Kill the Spid) will sometimes cause more problems. Doing data modifications in batches can circumvent this problem. See [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5636/optimize-large-sql-server-insert-update-and-delete-processes-by-using-batches/) for more details.

Hopefully this helps get you started. I've given you plenty to google. Please forgive any typos - I spun this up fast. Feel free to ask followup questions.